# Installing jupyterhub in minikube on a linux machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, jupyterhub

I'm using the instructions from [Zero to jupyterhub with kubernetes](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to install a jupyterhub in a minikube:

When I run the  command in step 2 shown below:

```
RELEASE=jhub   
NAMESPACE=jhub

~/minik$ helm upgrade --install $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub   --namespace $NAMESPACE    --version 0.7.0   --values config.yaml  --debug --dry-run
```

I get this error:

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '42995'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:42995"

[debug] Fetched jupyterhub/jupyterhub to
 /home1/chrisj/.helm/cache/archive/jupyterhub-0.7.0.tgz

Release "jhub" does not exist. Installing it now.
[debug] CHART PATH: /home1/chrisj/.helm/cache/archive/jupyterhub-0.7.0.tgz

Error: render error in "jupyterhub/templates/proxy/autohttps/service.yaml": template: jupyterhub/templates/proxy/autohttps/service.yaml:1:26: executing "jupyterhub/templates/proxy/autohttps/service.yaml" at <.Values.proxy.https....>: can't evaluate field https in type interface {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed Jupyterhub on minikube correctly using the provided tutorial, then I deleted it using helm delete, and tried to deploy it again with `helm upgrade --install`. I got similar error as you have posted. For me using:
`helm delete --purge jhub` solved the problem.

PS: If this will not help you, please provide some more details, like `helm version`, `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Comment: I'll try your suggestion tomorrow and let you know the result

Comment: Now I'm getting insufficient  me try to sign in to the jupyterhub

Comment: I was note sure if that matters, you can try to run minikube with more memory and cpu as if I remember correctly minikube uses 1GB of RAM by default. 
`minikube stop && minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192` (adjust the values for yourself)